# Set search result page preference globally

Tags: 2013, search, search-results-webpart

On SharePoint 2013 search result page there is a "Preference" menu where the current user can for example change default behaviour how documents should be opened (client application or web-browser).

This setting will override any open-behaviour specified in Central Admin or Site Collection.

Is there a way to set this globally for all users, with powershell for example? To push out this change so that all users has the same default setting.

Answer (score 1):

Found part of the solution needed for your problem in a blog comment by some guy named Marcus (http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2014/03/26/sharepoint-2013-search-open-in-client.aspx):

```
private void EnsureOpenInClient()
{
    UserPreference preference = UserPreference.GetUserPreference();
    if (!preference.IsSettingEnabled(UserPreference.Settings.OpenDocumentsInClient))
    {
        preference.EnableSetting(UserPreference.Settings.OpenDocumentsInClient);
        UserPreference.SetUserPreference(preference);
    }
}
```

According to MSDN it looks like the code always runs in the context of the current user but there is an overload where a context can be passed:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj276799.aspx

So I think it should be able to add some impersonation code first like this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration;

// replace domain and username to your needs or get a list of all users from somewhere (e.g. web.AllUsers)
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("Domain\username");
SPSite impSite = new SPSite(siteURL, user.UserToken);
SPWeb impWeb = impSite.OpenWeb();

// Get contex from impersonated user and use that to get preferences
var ctx = SPContext.GetContext(impWeb);
UserPreference preferenceInContext = UserPreference.GetUserPreference(false, ctx);

// change settings of user
if (!preferenceInContext.IsSettingEnabled(UserPreference.Settings.OpenDocumentsInClient))
{
    preferenceInContext.EnableSetting(UserPreference.Settings.OpenDocumentsInClient);
    UserPreference.SetUserPreference(preferenceInContext);
}
```

Haven't tested this myself yet!